# How to test OpenLDAP of my yocto-base Linux distribution

Tags: ldap, openldap

I've found that in my Yocto distribution I can install OpenLDAP **that is an open source implementation of the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol**.
Before starting the addition of this package to my Yocto distribution I would like to know how can I test it.

In this moment I have in mind following questions:

- I don't know the name of the LDAP client that I'll find in the image after the addition of OpenLDAP package
- I don't know if, somewhere in Internet, exists  a LDAP Server that I can use to connect to check the OpenLDAP working
- In my company there is an Active Directory service that, I know, use LDAP as protocol for interactions. Can I use it for my tests?

I hope my requests are clear and that someone can help me to do first steps on this topic.

Thanks